# Conditionally Serialize Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to conditionally serialize an attribute like so:

```
# answer.rb
serialize :content, :if => :has_options
attr_accessible :content, :form_id, :question_id
belongs_to :question

def has_options
  !self.answer.question.options.blank?
end
```

I've tried this but it's a no go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no conditional option to `serialize`.

What I would do is remove the `:content` from `attr_accessible` and do a `before_save` filter in which you set the `:content` under your conditions